# Javascript, HTML5 (canvas) progressbar with update

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, progress-bar

I'm looking for the best way to do a progress bar (in my case it's a life bar for a game) in an html5 canvas.

I don't know if it's better to use javascript and dom element, or draw this bar directly in the canvas.

I need an update function, for example `myBar.updateValue(40)`, and I need to show the new bar without refresh all the page or all the canvas, of course.

Do you know something like that? An existing script? Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming since you're using HTML5 Canvas for the game, you don't care about browsers that suck? (or in other words, internet explorer)

Comment: [Bootstrap has a CSS component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress).

Comment: Are you building a game in canvas but got stuck on the progress bar?!

Comment: [how to create a progressbar with canvas](http://www.splashnology.com/article/how-to-create-a-progress-bar-with-html5-canvas/478/)

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for bootstrap, i'm go try this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s very easy in HTML/CSS:

```
<style>
    #progress-holder{width:400px;height:20px;background:grey}
    #progress{width:0;height:100%;background:black}
</style>
<div id="progress-holder">
    <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
    function updateValue(perc) {
        progress.style.width = perc+'%';
    }
    updateValue(40);
</script>
```

**DEMO**: http://jsbin.com/EGAzAZEK/1/edit

And animating with CSS: http://jsbin.com/EGAzAZEK/3/edit

Comment: I don't like use settimeout, do you have an example with CSS ?

Comment: I should add this isn't HTML5 canvas method.... Unless you plan to use position:absolute with z-index over the top of a canvas to create the effect that its in the canvas, otherwise you need to use `fillrect`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class='progress'>
    <div class='progress-bar' data-width='//Enter a percent value here'>
        <div class='progress-bar-text'>
            Progress: <span class='data-percent'>//This is auto-generated by the script</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}

.progress {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
.progress-bar {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(66, 139, 202);
}
.progress-bar-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

    /*
    Do not change the values below,
    unless you want your text to display away from the bar itself. */
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.progress-bar').each(function (){    
    var datawidth = $(this).attr('data-width');

    $(this).find("span.data-percent").html(datawidth + "%");

    $(this).animate({
        width: datawidth + "%"
    }, 800);
});
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TLAx/6/)

The HTML `data-width` attribute is used to track the percent the bar should be set to. Change it to your liking.

The jQuery script works with ALL progress bars on your page (See the JSFiddle, so you don't have to copy and paste the same jQuery for every new progress bar. 
(Just be sure to keep the structure of the HTML, or change it to your liking).

The div "progress" is just an expander, it can be named whatever your want - without you having to change the jQuery.

EDIT:
If you can use Javascript & HTML, don't use a canvas. Canvas (imho) are good for only 1 thing: Seat bookings for concerts, theaters and alike.